# How to use subscript operator overloading in linklist using c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, singly-linked-list

I want to use subscript operator overloading in linklist but everytime it give me Segmentation fault (core dumped) ERROR! MY TASK IS : (Overload [] operator. Use for loop in main to display it.) I ALSO PROVIDING THE TASK LINK BELOW
//task link
[LINK OF TASK] https://anonymfile.com/r1XKK/dsa-a3.pdf

//MY CODE IS :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class LinkedList
{
private:

class Node
{
public:
int data;
Node * next;
Node(int data)
{
    this->data = data;
    this->next = NULL;
}
};
public:
Node *head;
LinkedList(){
head = NULL;
}
//Write a copy constructor. Also copy must be deep.
LinkedList(LinkedList& S)
    {
        head = S.head;
    }
//Overload [] operator. Use for loop in main to display it. 
void operator[](int i) {
    head->data = i;
}
void InsertAtEnd(int data){
    if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = new Node(data);
            return;
        }
        Node * temp = head;
        while (temp->next != NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = new Node(data);
    
    }
void Insert(int d1, int d2)//Add the node of data d2 after the node with data d1. If d2 is not available add it to the end.
{
    if (head == NULL)
        {
            Node * n = new Node(d2);
            n->next = head;
            head = n;
            return;
        }
        Node * temp = head;
        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            if (temp->data == d1)
            {
                Node * temp1 = temp->next;
                temp->next = new Node(d2);
                temp->next->next = temp1;
            }
            temp = temp->next;
        }
}
void Delete(int data){
     Node * todelete;
            if(head->data == data){
                todelete = head;
                head = head->next;
                free(todelete);
                return;
            }
            Node *temp = head;
            while(temp->next != NULL){
                if(temp->next->data == data){
                todelete = temp->next;
                temp->next = temp->next->next;
                free(todelete);
                break;
            }
                    temp = temp->next;
            }
} // Deletes a node with data.
int getSize(){
    Node * temp = head;
        int size = 0;
        while(temp != NULL){
        temp = temp->next;
        size++; 
        }
        return size;
} //returns the count of elements in the list
bool IsEmpty(){
    if(head == NULL){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
} //Returns true if empty.
void Merge(Node * list){
    //merge
    Node * temp  = head;
    while(temp != NULL){
        if(temp->next == NULL and list != NULL){
            temp->next = list;
            break;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    //DISPLAY
        while(head!=NULL){
            cout<<head->data<<"->";
            head=head->next;
        }
        cout<<"NULL"<<endl;
} //Merges the to the calling class.
void Erase(){
    Node * erase;
    while(head!= NULL){
        erase = head;
        head = head->next;
        head = NULL;
    }
    free(erase);

} //Deletes every node in an array.
void SelectiveErase(int num) //Find num and delete everything after num.
{
     Node * temp = head;
     Node * todelete;
        while(temp != NULL){
            if(temp->data == num){
                Node * erase = temp->next;
            while(temp->next != NULL){
                erase = temp->next;
                temp->next = temp->next->next;
                temp->next = NULL;
            }
                free(erase);
                break;
            }
                temp = temp->next;
        }
}
int FindNCount(int find)//Find and return count of all occurrence.
{
    int counter  = 0;
    bool flag = false;
    Node * temp = head;
    while(temp->data!= find){
        temp = temp->next;
        counter++;
}
        return counter;
}
int RemoveDuplicate(int find)//Find and remove every duplicate element in the list. Make //elements unique.
{
    Node * temp = head;
    Node *temp1;
    while(temp != NULL){
        temp1 = temp;
        while(temp1->next != NULL){
             if(temp->data == temp1->next->data and temp->data == find and temp1->next->data == find){
                        Node *todelete = temp1->next;
                        temp1->next = temp1->next->next;
                        free(todelete);
             }
             else{
                temp1 = temp1->next;
             }
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return find;

}
void FindNReplace(int find, int data)//Find and replace all occurrence recursively.
{
     Node * temp = head;
            while(temp != NULL){
                if(temp->data == find){
                    temp->data = data;
                    break;
                }
                    temp = temp->next;
            }


}
void Display(){
    static Node * temp= head;
    if(temp == NULL){ cout << "NULL" << endl; return;}
    cout << temp->data<<"->";
    temp = temp->next;
    Display();
}
};
void Swap() // swap the contents of one list with another list of same type and size. Also write parameter
{
    LinkedList L,L1; 
    cout<<"AFTER SWAPING THE VALUE OF FIRST LIST \n";
    while(L.head != NULL && L1.head != NULL){
        int temp = L.head->data;
        L.head->data = L1.head->data;
        L1.head->data = temp;
        cout<<L.head->data<<"\n";
        L.head = L.head->next;
        L1.head = L1.head->next;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
int main()
{
// You must call Display function after every function.
    LinkedList L{};
    L[23];
    // LinkedList L1;
    
    // L1.InsertAtEnd(5);
    // L1.InsertAtEnd(6);
    //L.Erase();
    // cout<<L.FindNCount(1)<<endl;
    //L.SelectiveErase(2);
    //L.Display();
    //L.Merge(L1.head);
    //L.RemoveDuplicate(2);
    //L.Display();
    //Swap();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you think about a vector or even an array, what does the subscript operator really do? What is your *actual* "task"? Please copy-paste the full assignment or exercise text into your question.

Comment: `head = NULL;` in your code you never actually create a `Node`. head is a nullptr and then `head->data` is undefined. You need a node before you can access its value

Comment: And how do you expect to access node number 23 in an empty list?

Comment: you also need to read this https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

Comment: Really this code shows you have some serious gaps in your understanding. The operator [] is supposed to **get** a value from the list, it is not supposed to set an item in the list, nor is supposed to `cout <<` values (that happens in main). Also `head = S.head;` is not a deep copy, it's the opposite, a shallow copy.

Comment: Really you cannot do this task until you have a working linked list, One that you can add nodes to, which you will later access using `operator[]`. There's no evidence in this question that you have a working linked list. So that's your first task, write some working linked list code. Then try the operator[] task.

Comment: The semantics of the index operator is 'give me the n-th` item in the container. It might work but accessing list items through it will be slow. You would need to start at the start of your list every time and then move forward to the `n-th` item. Basically changing access complexity from O(1) to O(n). So no not a good idea for lists.

Comment: Usually the signature of the operator is `DataType& operator[](size_t index);` or `DataType const& operator[](size_t index) const;` . The operator rarely has side effects for list-like structures. Your operator implementation would set the index as the data value of the first element, if there was one and print something to the console. That's not something anyone would expect from a index operator of a list.

Comment: That is also the reason C++'s list https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list doesn't have an index operator. And `std::list` is what you should use, unless you are doing an excercise for a datastructures class.

Comment: For C++ I strongly recommend going with the `nullptr` keyword instead of the `NULL` macro btw, since `nullptr` isn't implicitly convertible to `int` which `NULL` may be depending on the standard lib.

Comment: @PepijnKramer: There could be use cases for that. A container that would only contain a small number of objects, with a lot of insertions and removals, and few direct accesses. But I acknowledge that it is really a corner case ;-) . That being said, it may be an interesting home work, for learning about custom containers, and OP has still a lot to learn...

Comment: @SergeBallesta Oh sure, learning how to implement an indexing operator is a good use case (to learn operator overloading, what semantics is expected for an indexing operator and more, that what seems nice for client code can have unintended consequences for performance etc.). I think OP can learn a lot today :)

Comment: fwiw, even if your `LinkedList` would be all fine, the code in `main` would be wrong. If a user tries to access an element in an empty container, its not the containers fault. It is common to do no bounds checking and let out-of-bounds access be undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overloading the subscript operator should return something. The assignment looks a bit vague, but I hope this will fix it:

```cpp
//Overload [] operator. Use for loop in main to display it. 
Node* operator[](int i) {
    Node* nodePtr = head;
    int counter = 0;
    while (nodePtr != NULL && counter != i) {
        nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
        counter++;
    }
    return nodePtr;
}
```